# Photoshop / Take the color out of the selection

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop

Please help in solving the following problem:

I need to pick up color from a selected randomly shaped area, probably quite small relative to the image and having no known position on the canvas beforehand, with an eyedropper.
This needs to be done automatically, without manual clicks.

With my skills, I was only able to write a script that takes a sample from the center of the current document, which doesn't solve the problem, but it gives direction.

```
 // Set reference for active document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

// remove any sample first
srcDoc.colorSamplers.removeAll();


// get width and height of image
var w = srcDoc.width.value;
var h = srcDoc.height.value;

// get positions of the center of the image
//var x = 0;
//var y = 0;
var x = Math.round(w/2);
var y = Math.round(h/2);

// will pick a sample from the middle of the image
var px = [UnitValue(x) , UnitValue(y)];
var Sampler = srcDoc.colorSamplers.add(px);

// Copy RGB Values of current layer  with 3 decimal spaces
var myColor = Sampler.color;
var rgb_R = Math.round(myColor.rgb.red*1000)/1000;
var rgb_G = Math.round(myColor.rgb.green*1000)/1000;
var rgb_B = Math.round(myColor.rgb.blue*1000)/1000;



set(rgb_R, rgb_G, rgb_B, "photoshopPicker");
function set(red, Grn, blue, source) {
    var c2t = function (s) {
        return app.charIDToTypeID(s);
    };

    var s2t = function (s) {
        return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);
    };

    var descriptor = new ActionDescriptor();
    var descriptor2 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var reference = new ActionReference();

    reference.putProperty( s2t( "color" ), s2t( "foregroundColor" ));
    descriptor.putReference( c2t( "null" ), reference );
    descriptor2.putDouble( s2t( "red" ), red );
    descriptor2.putDouble( c2t( "Grn " ), Grn );
    descriptor2.putDouble( s2t( "blue" ), blue );
    descriptor.putObject( s2t( "to" ), s2t( "RGBColor" ), descriptor2 );
    descriptor.putString( s2t( "source" ), source );
    executeAction( s2t( "set" ), descriptor, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

I haven't found ways to do this in PS itself without human involvement and I have no experience in scripting, but scripting seems to be the correct solution to the problem. It would be great to have a ready-made script for such an operation.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this requires more infornation. How the script would know where you want to pick the color from?

Comment: Да.
В документе будет подготовлена выделенная область. Именно из нее нужно забрать цвет.

Скажем, есть условная область площадью 50px.
Она будет иметь один цвет. Его нужно забрать.

Но эта область может иметь случайную форму. Т.е. не обязательно это будет квадрат. А так же может иметь случайные координаты.

Comment: Since selection only have bounding boxes, you'll want to convert your selection to a path first, then use any algorithm to find a point inside the resulting polygon (for example https://observablehq.com/@scarysize/finding-random-points-in-a-polygon )

Comment: You can get the colour of an x,y pixel with `var pointSample = app.activeDocument.colorSamplers.add([(x),(y)]);`